# Angular 2 RC5 - Share variable with children views on outlet-router

Tags: angular, routes

I have the next folder

- component1
- component2

  - children1
  - children2
  - children3

Inside component2, I have a variable with all info needed for the three subcomponents, the children just show the info but with different templates, I dont want to have the same variable in the three components.

Answer (score 0):

Your components should be isolated from outside environment, so if you don't want to pass them through the Input you can put them to **service** which is related to component2, and then inject to each component.

The structure will be like this:

- component1_folder

  - component1
- component2_folder

  - component2
  - component2_service
  - children1
  - children2
  - children3